# onEdit Function copy data to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't know how to convert it to the onEdit function.

I have the following code, how can I convert it to run automatically using the onEdit function?

```js
function copyDataBasedOnDate() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("L1");
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("L2");
  
  var currentDate = new Date(); // Current date
  var currentDateString = formatDate(currentDate); // Current date string
  
  var dataRange = sheet1.getRange("B4:Q" + sheet1.getLastRow());
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  
  var sheet2DataRange = sheet2.getRange("B4:Q" + sheet2.getLastRow());
  
  var rowIndex = 0; // Row index in sheet2
  
  for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    var rowData = dataValues[i];
    var dateValue = new Date(rowData[5]); // Date value in column G
    var dateString = formatDate(dateValue); // Date string in column G
    
    if (dateString == currentDateString) {
      sheet2DataRange.offset(rowIndex, 0, 1, rowData.length).setValues([rowData]);
      rowIndex++;
    }
  }
}

// Function to format date value to "yyyy-MM-dd" format
function formatDate(date) {
  if (date instanceof Date) {
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    
    var formattedDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    return formattedDate;
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide more information about what you want the `onEdit` to do? `onEdit` is really just a reserved function in Google Script, you can see the simplest example on their website: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite
Most likely you want to restrict when the `onEdit` triggers using `e.range` from the event object: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: What you are doing with your onedit is going to greatly affect the performance of you spreadsheet.  I would avoid doing this for every edit.  I would think you should limit your actions to the row that is being edited and utilize the event object to avoid the use of unnecessary functions in your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.